# Coroutine cancellation with HMS

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm adapting my application to HMS. When I cancel launched coroutine, catch and trying to log CancellationException to HMS crashlytics, my app crashed with strange logs. If I omit this exception and didn't log it to crashlytics using method `AGConnectCrash.getInstance().recordException(throwable)` coroutine cancellation doesn't lead to app crash. Can someone help with that problem?

**Crash logs**

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 at com.huawei.agconnect.crash.internal.bean.Event$Builder.summary(Unknown Source:5) at com.huawei.agconnect.crash.internal.log.AGCCrashNonFatal.collectInfo(Unknown Source:41) at com.huawei.agconnect.crash.internal.log.AGCCrashNonFatal.logException(Unknown Source:0) at com.huawei.agconnect.crash.internal.log.AGCCrashCore$4.run(Unknown Source:6) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)`

**SomeCodeExample**

```
private fun loadData() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            data.value = someApiCall()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
object Logger {
        
    fun log(e: Throwable?) {
        if (e != null) {
            AGConnectCrash.getInstance().recordException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your input parameter type is incorrect. You put the string instead of the stack information. You are advised to enter the document type. If a character string is forcibly entered, the system crashes. And in later versions, a judgment protection mechanism will be added.

[image]

For Details,pls kindly refer [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agccrashplugin-cordova-0000001063650444#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001063650444__section949720119296?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: You refer to docs for cross-platform `AGCCrashPlugiin` but I'm using in my project `AGConnectCrash` and according to docs, method `public void recordException(Throwable throwable)`

Records a non-fatal exception.

Comment: It's a bit strange because all other non-fatal exceptions logs to crashlytics using that method without any problems, only if I log `CancellationException` causing crash

Comment: hi @slothdeboss, Do you have any code snippets and how you invoke it? Seems like there have no the `CancellationException` method you're talking about.

Comment: hi @shirley, add some code snippet up there

Comment: May I ask how you constructed the `CancellationException`and what’s your version number? if you could add an `e.getStackTrace().size()` log print on either of these places on the diagram that would be great.https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Pk5.png

Comment: we have map in our app and app launch api request every time map triggers onIdleListener, if coroutine job isn't already complete we cancel it and reasign it with new job, that's throws `JobCancellationException`. Stack trace size for JobCancellationException is 0

Comment: Sorry@slothdeboss,The R&D team confirmed that this is a new issue and will be optimized in later versions. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: No problem @shirley. I was glad to help and will look forward to further updates! :)